# Should I mention that I'm able to self fund my degree in my SOP?

Tags: masters, application, united-states, statement-of-purpose

Should I mention that I'm able to self fund my degree in my SOP? I don't find anywhere else in the application process where I can communicate such information.

I'm a prospective international student applying in the US in the field of Electrical and Computer Engineering.

Comment: With respect to which country are you a prospective international student?  That is, which country are you applying to? The answer, can vary across countries. For instance, in Italy you don't specify this kind of information in the application process for a PhD, but you can choose later, once accepted, to not be funded.

Comment: I will be applying in the US. In the field of Electrical and Computer Engineering to be specific.

Comment: Lots of discussion here: http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/45746/8722

Comment: blmoore: I would have to say that most of the discussed points are exclusively tolerated towards PhD funding which may not translate well with masters. Especially that self funding masters is very common unlike PhD

Answer (score 1):

At least here funds to finance graduate students are scarce, so somebody who will be an asset without cutting into said funding, is clearly welcome. You should definitely state that in your application, by attaching proof of your funding. If said funding is e.g. a competitive scholarship from your origin country, it should be a definite plus in your application.