# Have money, but am old--how will these affect PhD application

Tags: phd, funding, age, discrimination

In terms of academics, I think when I finish my masters (in two years), I will have a strong application with excellent grades, good recommendations, and a potentially very interesting project (albeit in an obscure, underfunded field).
I am going for a PhD because it is something I have wanted to do my whole life (like since I was eight), but I first had a lucrative career in a completely unrelated field.
I now have sufficient personal wealth to fund the costs of a PhD program, but I am also old enough to be someone's grandparent.
I want to be accepted on my academic merits and a good match for the institution, but I don't want to be rejected for a lack of funding (because it is truly a non-issue for me) nor my age.
How are these two factors going to impact my chances of acceptance?
Any suggestions for how to minimize the disadvantages?
Thanks much.

Comment: Welcome to Academia.SE. Interesting situation, but I think both of these have been addressed before. In particular: [How old is too old for a PhD?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/3426) and [I am able to self-fund a PhD, how can I use this when applying?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/45746). If these links do not address your question, please [edit] your post to clarify why not, and we can consider reopening.